# angular app old javascript file is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, caching, browser

I am using angular build with grunt and deployed on apache. I added a timestamp to my javascript file hoping that on each new build the browser will be forced to request the source so the users will have the new version.

But inspecting on all the browsers I see the following mismatch :
[image]

If I open the app in private browser the correct file is loaded. How come the new file is not loaded even in non-private since it has a different name created by adding the timestamp suffix ?

Comment: do you have some server side caching?

Comment: @MajoB Do you think it's hitting the sever? I was thinking the browser it's loading the file in the client side..not even touching the server.